# Javascript alternative to FBJS function getAbsoluteLeft

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am migrating a project from previous Facebook Api (FBJS) to the new API. There is a function with the name:

`getAbsoluteLeft()`

I have no idea why this is used. Can anyone provide its javascript alternate?

Comment: I'm not sure, I understand your question... but why not just look into source code of that function in facebook API?

Comment: sorry. but where can i get it? i have tried googeling.. havent found much

Answer (score 0):

According to what is described on the [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/)

getAbsoluteLeft:

> Same as getAbsoluteTop, but horizontally.

getAbsoluteTop:

> Returns the elements absolute position relative to the left of the
>   page. Useful because of lack of offsetParent support.

If you are using jQuery in iFrame, you can use the offset function to get left and top of the element.

```
var position = $(element).offset();
```

Comment: yes i pretty much dd the same thing $(element).postion().left and it worked.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I haven't found the code itself too.
Here's the similar code, I used in ony of my project

```
function getCoords(obj){
    if (getCoordsCache.obj == obj) {
    return getCoordsCache.pos;
    } else {
    var o = obj;
        var ret={'l':o.offsetLeft,'t':o.offsetTop,'w':o.offsetWidth,'h':o.offsetHeight}
        while(o=o.offsetParent){
            ret.l+=o.offsetLeft;
            ret.t+=o.offsetTop;
        }
        getCoordsCache.obj = obj;
        getCoordsCache.pos = ret;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

It returns object with `left` and `top` properties. So for `getAbsoluteLeft` just return `getCoords(obj).left`.

Using jQuery like in another answer is even better, if you have it.